# IIS returns a 503 error for one specific binding

Tags: iis, https, http-status-code-503

I have a windows server 2019 VM in Azure.
On this server I have multiple web sites running.
One web site has two URL's
For example https://api.oldcompanyname.com (192.1.1.5) and https://api.newcompanyname.com (192.1.1.6)
I have certificates for both, each has its own binding, and each has its own IP address.
Locally on the machine I can access both sites with no issue.
However remotely the old site URL pulls up just fine, but the new site URL gives me a 503 error.
I have checked the IIS logs and I don't see any of the 503 errors listed in there.
I checked the windows logs and there are no crashes with the AppPool and again running locally (with FQDN) works just fine so the site is loading.
Windows firewall is turned off.

In Azure we do have this server behind a Traffic Manager, PF Sense, and App Gateway.
I want to rule out any issues on this server before I go searching in one of these areas
Funny thing is that even from another machine inside the network I get the 503 on this one binding and I don't think that that connection would go through any of above items as it is an internal address it is using.

Any ideas?

Comment: 503 are usually recorded in HTTP error logs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/error-logging-http-apis#kinds-of-errors-that-the-http-api-logs

Comment: I agree that they should be in the log, but they are not. All I see are the 200 requests when I access the site from the other binding or this the second binding locally. This leads me to believe that this issue is external to the server.

Comment: You can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis